# Revealing 'code' hidden button in TinyMCE4 and Wordpress 3.9.x

Tags: tinymce

Please, I need help with Wordpress 3.9.1 and TinyMCE4.

Before, with Wordpress 3.8.x and TinyMCE3, I have used this code in my *functions.php* theme file to reveal the hidden 'code' button in TinyMCE3:

```
function my_mce_buttons_2($buttons) {
$buttons[] = 'code';
return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2’);
```

The 'code' button is used to open a little window in TinyMCE which shows the real HTML code.

The before code is from [a Wordpress Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons).

Well, now, with Wordpress 3.9 and TinyMCE4, this do NOT work anymore. I can't reveal this button.

But, instead, if I follow the Wordpress Codex instructions linked before, and use 'superscript' or 'subscript' instead of 'code'... IT WORKS!! But don't know why, because 'code' is one of the [buttons listed in the TinyMCE site as available](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x%3aButtons/controls).

Please, help me, I don't have the programing knowledge to solve this on my own. THANKS.

--
Please, excuse my poor english, it's not my mother language.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have find the answer to my question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144705/unable-to-add-code-button-to-tinymce-toolbar). Seems like the Wordpress Team forgot to add the TinyMCE4 ‘code’ plugin in the Wordpress 3.9.1 release. Well, thanks to all!